# How to get sms list as convesations in every android device 2.2+

Tags: android, list, sms

I need to get list of text messages and display them like in stock aplication or Go sms pro. I'm using following code:

```
uriSms = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations");  
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[] {"*"}, null, null, "date DESC");   
cursor.moveToFirst();  
do{    
    try{
        String address = cursor.getString(32);  
        if(address == null){
            address = "";   //phone number
        }else{
            address = getContactName(address);  
        }
        String body = cursor.getString(2);  
        System.out.println("======> Mobile number => "+address);  
        System.out.println("=====> SMS Text => "+body);  
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

It works on my galaxy tab ( android 2.2 ) but on my s3 (ICS) application crashes at start. I don't want to parse mms so i tried using

```
uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations");
```

but it didn't work on both devices. I googled a lot to find a solution and I found nothing. I have only discovered that access to sms conversations depends on android os and device. My purpose is to make application which support every android device 2.2+. In stock application they using Thread.CONTENT_URI to get sms list as conversations eg.

```
Threads.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("simple", "true").build();
```

but class Thread isn't provided with source code and I can't find it in internet.
What can I do to make my application run on every android device (2.2+) just like Handcent Sms or GO sms pro.

Comment: I think this is the solution to the above problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553046/sgs-3-bug-related-to-sms-conversations-list

Answer (score 2):

Your code is crashing because you are assuming that the queried table contains a column named `address`, where not all android versions store the address in the conversation. To check the structure of the table you can display its column names and contents via the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> conversation = new ArrayList<>();

Uri    uri    = Uri.parse( "content://sms/conversations/" );
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( uri, null, null ,null, null );

startManagingCursor( cursor );
if( cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
    String count = Integer.toString( cursor.getCount() );

    while( cursor.moveToNext() ) {
        String result = "";

        for( int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++ ) {
            result = result + "\nindex " + i + "\n column is "
                + cursor.getColumnName( i ) + "\nvalue is " + cursor.getString( i );
        }

        result = result + "\n new conversation";
        conversation.add( result );
    }
}

cursor.close();
```

A possible workaround is to use the `thread_id` as a parameter to search for the address as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> conversation = new ArrayList<>();
// We may use sms/sent or sms/inbox
Uri    uri    = Uri.parse( "content://sms" );
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( uri, null, "thread_id" + " = " + threadId ,null, null );

startManagingCursor( cursor );
if( cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
    String count = Integer.toString( cursor.getCount() );

    while( cursor.moveToNext() ){
        String result = "";

        for( int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++ ) {
            result = result + "\nindex " + i + "\n column is "
                + cursor.getColumnName( i ) + "\nvalue is " + cursor.getString( i );
        }

        result = result + "\n new conversation";
        conversation.add( result );
    }
}

cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final StringBuilder msgString = new StringBuilder();
// ************** SMS ********************* 
List<SMSData> smsList = new ArrayList<SMSData>();

Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);
//startManagingCursor(c);

// Read the sms data and store it in the list
if(c.moveToFirst()) {
    for(int i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

        SMSData sms = new SMSData();
        sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
        sms.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")).toString());
        sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
        smsList.add(sms);

        String address  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
        String mbody    = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
        String mdate    = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")).toString();
        Date dt = new Date(Long.valueOf(mdate));

        msgString.append(address + "<-||->");
        msgString.append(mbody  + "<-||->");
        msgString.append(dt  + "<-||->");
        msgString.append(mdate + "<--!-->");

        c.moveToNext();
    }       
}

c.close();
```